# Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2 issue

Tags: java, android, gradle

I found an old android project from github but I can't run it. It gives me a lot of errors.
like

```
9:13 PM Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2.
                Searched in the following locations:
                https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.2/gradle-3.6.2.pom
                https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.2/gradle-3.6.2.jar
                Required by:
                :Android-Hospital-Management-Client-master:unspecified
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (8 s 451 ms)
```

I thought it because that not update the dependencies and I change compile to implementation like this and update all the dependices like the below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shivam.openmrs"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    implementation 'br.com.liveo:navigationdrawer-material:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.8.2'
    implementation 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:@aar'
    implementation 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.2.4'
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.5.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    implementation fileTree(dir : 'libs', include: 'commons-lang3-3.4.jar')
    implementation fileTree(dir : 'libs', include: 'commons-io-2.4.jar')
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.0'
}
```

This is a photo of that error um getting after run it.

Error:
[image: Error pic].

How I fix this and run it ?

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although very good, it is better to add an image than a link, since URLs can change over time.

Answer (score 2):

Change the gradle version to newer version such as 4.0.2 in build.gradle and sync project

Answer (score 0):

please try it

Click File > Settings (on macOS, Android Studio > Preferences ) to open the Settings dialog.

In the left pane, expand Build, Execution, Deployment and then click Gradle .

Under Global Gradle settings, uncheck the Offline work checkbox.

Click Apply or OK for your changes to take effect.

Comment: I can't find Global Gradle settings under in Gradle :(

Answer (score 0):

It would definitely give a lot of errors because your android studio configuration is too different from any other project configuration.

It also happens with me many times. If I found one error then more other errors came out.
but I solved the way to get out of here

The main stuff to run the projects is the XML and Java and little bit of drawable and value.
So just copy all of that and paste into your project Because this stuff doesn't get changed with time.

I hope it would help you
And if it is much important to you so you would definitely do the steps given.
So, have a nice day!!!
Stay learning, Stay safe

:)

Answer (score 0):

Please find this panel at the left of Android Studio to check offline mode

---

[image: Find this one for Gradle offline mode setting]
Please click on sixth logo 
[image]
After this please run following command to clear gradle cache:

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/
```

after that please click on `Invalidate Caches/Restart` from File menu then further processing will happen which downloads all the libraries again so it takes time but also resolves this issue.

Comment: now it give me this error - 10:52 PM Gradle sync failed: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2 available for offline mode.
    Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (878 ms)

Comment: I updated some further steps please check updated code

Comment: Please again click that offline mode button again and follow this steps again

Comment: This error came now - 11:45 PM Gradle sync failed: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-all.zip'.
    Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (166 ms)

Comment: Please use latest gradle version